# How do I uninstall .NET 4.6 RC?

Tags: .net

I know now I should have installed Visual Studio 2015 RC on a VM, but I didn't, so when I uninstalled it, .NET 4.6 RC didn't leave with it unfortunately.  This probably wouldn't be an issue, but when I tried to install a particular extension into VS 2013 the installer wouldn't continue, saying that it couldn't detect the right version of the .NET framework (it was looking for 4.5). 4.6 is an in place upgrade so that means VS 2013 is now running on it as well as can be seen when going to the Help -> About dialog.

I see .NET 4.6 RC in the list of programs in the control panel so surely I can just uninstall it there and be done with it.  So that is in fact what I did and the uninstaller reported success.

No go. The extension still complains about the wrong version of the .NET framework and VS 2013 still says it's running on 4.6.  I thought maybe this was just a registry setting that the uninstaller forgot to reset, but when I took a look at System.dll located in the .NET 4 install directory, it in fact shows the version number as 4.6.000.30. I thought maybe a repair on VS 2013 might do the trick but that didn't work either.

So how do I get rid of this sucker?  Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall every version of the .Net Framework from Programs and Features from the Windows Control Panel. You might want to use [.NET Framework Cleanup Tool User's Guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx) to be sure.

Now to completly remove .Net Framework you need to uninstall the Windows Update that brought it.
As told when you try to uninstall .Net Framework via the cmd prompt with /uninstall
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965(v=vs.110).aspx

So go to Programs and Features from the Windows Control Panel, show updates and delete the KB3033095(.Net Framework 4.6) update. Personnally I had to delete the KB2934520(.Net Framework 4.5.2) too.

Repair Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 in Programs and Features from the Windows Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to go to installed updates and search KB3102467 (for Windows Server 2012R2). Uninstall this update , restart the server.Hope this will help you !

Answer (score -1):

Go to "add remove programs"
In Control Panel, it is here 
Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features

and press Key M, to go to close to Microsoft.
You should see Microsoft .Net 4.6 and related items, select one by one and click uninstall on top for each.